# Proper (and least annoying) way to resize a browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, resize, window

I am working on a project where I need to resize a small pop-up window (which is a chat window of about 500x400px) to be larger to contain a different type of content in certain circumstances.

What is the best way to resize a small pop-up window to be larger?  Is it best to just use:

```
window.resizeTo(width,height);
```

I looked for a jQuery way to do this, but didn't see any.  I was hoping there was a way to resize a window smoothly, but I don't see any way.  Am I missing something?  The only other option I see is to pop-up a new pop-up from the old pop-up -- which to me seams even worse.

Please, don't respond with "don't resize a window" -- because I know that it sucks and is generally a bad user experience.  However, I'm freelancing for a company that is working within the framework of a legacy system that hasn't really been updated in a decade and this seems like the least bad option so far.

Comment: Tell the user that you're resizing it :P

Comment: YOu could simply run the resizeTo stuff within a timer-controlled loop, but that seems rather painful, as it'd most likely lock up the browser as it redraws the content at each resizing step. Just kick the window to the right size once and leave it alone otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's .height() and .width() functions should be able to handle this by running, for example:

```
$(window).height(400);
```

In addition, it sounds like you will need to get the size of the content BEFORE you do the actual resize function. If it's a static value and you know beforehand, simply hard-code the values. If it's dynamic, you can do the following:

```
$(window).height($('#yourcontent').height());
```

You might need to do some testing especially for cross-browser and adjust the math a bit for different browsers since they tend to change line-heights, padding, etc.

BTW - this is a horrible thing you are doing, as you said, but I've been in that situation before so I can relate :-/ Sometimes the "next step in evolution" is still really really far behind the present world. Hope those managers get a clue and instead of spending dollars supporting legacy stuff will consider investing in more modern & flexible techniques. They might be surprised that the real costs involved (increased user productivity, faster dev / enhancement cycles, lower TCO) are actually very close to simply maintaining.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a new browser window? You can create a new div on top of your document using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the websites this will run on aren't operated by me, so I have to take the original pop-up as granted, even though your suggestion would certainly be preferable in an ideal situation.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to tell you "don't resize a window", but the users of your application will tell you **"you cannot resize my window"**, because there usually are browser-settings that disallow those actions in most cases.

By this the only safe way is to reopen the window with the desired new size.